# rawQuery selectionArgs not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to query a database with code:

`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+MoneyDBOpenHelper.TABLE_RECORD+" where "+ MoneyDBOpenHelper.ACCOUNT_ID+" = ?",new String []{"1"});`

But it's not working at all,I didn't query any data.

---

While I abandon the usage of selectionArgs with code:

`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+MoneyDBOpenHelper.TABLE_RECORD+" where "+ MoneyDBOpenHelper.ACCOUNT_ID+" = 1",null});`

It's working,and I got the data I want.I think those 2 lines of code should compose the same function but they didn't,am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`1` is a number. `"1"` is a string.

This is a limitation of the Android dabase API; you should use parameters only for strings.

Comment: you mean I can't use any number in selectionArgs? or is there any way to use number in selectionArgs?

Comment: All parameters will be replaced as a string. You would have to use something like `CAST(? AS INTEGER)` in the SQL statement to convert it back into a number; it's easier to put numbers directly into the SQL statement.